# Sending two JSON via Ajax POST to Flask python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, rest, flask

Hello I'm trying to send two different json from my html/js template to my python `app.py` class

To send one json I used :

## html/JS :

```
("#btnSubmitAllRejets").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/rejets_modeles',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(maj_ref_modeles_json)
        }).done(function(result){
            //console.log(result)
        })

});
```

## PYTHON :

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
        maj_ref_modeles_json ={}
        for key in request.form.to_dict():
            maj_ref_modeles_json = json.loads(key)
```

No I tried to modify this line in my js code to send my two jsons :

```
//data: { JSON_1 : JSON.stringify(maj_ref_modeles_json), JSON_2 :JSON.stringify(maj_transco_modeles_json)},
```

and I get this error :

> Traceback
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

How can I fix this to have my 2 jsons sent to my python code ? Thank you

Comment: try to send json with key as data and the value as list of dictionaries

Comment: try to use quotes like "JSON_1" and "JSON_2", although see json formatters and validators online